# using RESTlet, XStream annotations seem to have no effect

Tags: java, restlet, xstream

Using @XStreamOmitField in my POJO seems to have no effect whatsoever. the annotated field still gets exposed in the xml or json representation.

```
@XStreamAlias("Pojo")
@Entity
public class Pojo {
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

    @XStreamOmitField
    private String hidden;

    public Pojo(String name, String hidden) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hidden = hidden;
    }
}
```

and in the ServerResource

```
@Get
public Pojo test() {
    Pojo pj= new Pojo("hansi","hinter");
    return pj;
}
```

gets me

```
<com.myComp.ORMTest.Pojo>
  <name>hansi</name>
  <hidden>hinter</hidden>
</com.myComp.ORMTest.Pojo>
```

Any ideas why the annotations are ignored?

Comment: Ok, this seems to be not the only problem in getting GAE, RESTlet and XStream working together. I'm looking for another solution now.

Comment: Hi, did the solution worked for you? How did you apply that? I'm having the same issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794041/using-xstream-extension-with-swagger-instead-of-jackson

Comment: @fireburn , Sorry, I have no recollection of how I resolved the problem. This was 11 years ago.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to tell XStream to explicitly process annotations:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.processAnnotations(MyClass.class);
```

Or, you should add this code to tell XStream to process all annotations:

```
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
```

Comment: Just a note for other seekers: auto detection of annotations only works for serialization, *not* deserialization. You have to process each class (or an array of them) in order to parse XML.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind:

1.) Did you tell XStream to parse the annotations?

2.) Does your web framework maybe use proxies to access the pojos and those don't delegate the annotations? (happened to a friend with Apache Tapestry)

Comment: Great leads. Will start digging in that direction.

Thanks